# Running commands in server through local python script

Tags: python-3.x, bash, ssh, server

I would like to run a batch of bash commands (all together) in a server shell through a python3 script in my local machine. 
The reason why I'm not running the python3 script on my laptop is that I can't create the same environment on the server and I want to keep the settings I have on my machine while executing the script.
What I would like to do is:
-Run python commands locally
-Run at a certain point those command on the server
-Wait for the end of server execution
-Continue running python script
(This will be done in a loop)

What I'm trying is to put all the commands in a bash script `ssh_commands.sh` and use the following command:

```
subprocess.call('cat ssh_commands.sh | ssh -T -S {} -p {} {}'.format(socket, port, user_host).split(),shell=True)
```

But when the execution of the script reaches that line get stuck until `subprocess.call` timeout. The execution of the script anyway won't take that much. The only way to stop the script before is through `Ctrl+C`

I've also tried to set up the ssh connection in the `~/.ssh/config` file but I'm getting the same result.

I know that ssh connection works fine and if I run `ssh_commands.sh` on the server manually, it runs without any problem.

Can somebody suggest:
- A way for fixing what I'm trying to do
- A better way for achieving the final result written above
- Some debugging way to find out what could be the problem
Thank you in advance

Comment: It's probably the pipe ... you need to run it as 2 `Popen`, set `stdout` to `PIPE` for the first then `stdin=proc.stdout`for the second.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To expand on my comment - and I haven't tested your specific case with ssh, could be there are other complications there). This is actually copy/pasted from my own code in a situation that I already know works.

```
from subprocess import Popen, PIPE, DEVNULL
from shlex import split as sh_split

proc1 = Popen(sh_split(file_cmd1), stdout=PIPE)
proc2 = Popen(file_cmd2, shell=True, stdin=proc1.stdout, stdout=PIPE)
proc1.stdout.close()
```

I have a specific reason to use `shell=True` in the second, but you should probably be able to use `shlex.split` there too I'm guessing.

Basically you're running one command, outputting to `PIPE´, then using this as input for the second command.

Comment: Glad to help :) if it worked please do mark it as the right answer :)